# Time-Efficient way of sending image between 2 Raspberry Pi

Tags: serialization, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, raspbian, i2c

I have to send a low resolution image (128x256) from one raspberry pi to another in the fastest way possible. What are some possible ways to approach this problem? Should I send bytes over I2C or set up some kind of LAN connection over which I could transmit (unidirectionally) images between the raspberrys using their IPs?  A delay of less than 0.5-1 second is preferable.

Comment: Have a look here https://befinitiv.wordpress.com/wifibroadcast-analog-like-transmission-of-live-video-data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your constraints and whether the two pis are networked, the [Dat Protocol](https://datproject.org/) is fast, works over a LAN using multicast UDP, and will handle the serialization/deserialization for you.

See also [try-dat](https://try-dat.com/)